# Load AdWords Conversion Tracking with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ajax, google-ads-api

I have to load a snippet for adwords in my app, but I have a problem when try to do this, the pixel doesn't work.

This is the error I got:

```
Missing HTTP Response
```

I'm using ui.router and the snippet have to hit in a view (my goal):

```
<div>
 more content here .....
 ......
 ......

<!-- Google Code Conversion Page -->
        <script type="text/javascript">    
          var google_conversion_id = 925xxxxx;
          var google_conversion_language = "en";
          var google_conversion_format = "3";
          var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
          var google_conversion_label = "S-wiCLWKoGUQ_xxxxx";
          var google_remarketing_only = false;  
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>

        <noscript>
          <div style="display:inline;">
            <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/925xxxxx/?label=S-wiCLWKoGUQ_OfCuQM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
          </div>
        </noscript>


</div>
```

What is the best practice and solution for doing that in AngularJS??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that this doesn't relate to Angular. Missing HTTP response means that script is detected on the website, but doesn't execute. **Would it work if you add http / https to src attribute?**

Anyway, I would strongly recommend you to **use something like Google Tag Manger** to add such a tags, so you don't need to change source code everytime you need to change remarketing / conversion tag. This also helps you to avoid such a problems.

[Debugging no HTTP response for AdWords](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722021?hl=en). Official support pages.
[Google Tag Manager - adding AdWords conversions](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6105160?hl=en)